# Can't install myEclipse on MacBook Pro with Yosemite

Tags: install, macos

After updating to Yosemite, I find that I can't install myEclipse again.

> Installation error:insufficient memory,zero virtual memory.

I also tried the `sysctl vm.swapusage` command, the result is

> vm.swapusage: total = 0.00M  used = 0.00M  free = 0.00M  (encrypted)`

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: How did you install Java (note the error message might be from Java and not the OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the installer again. MyElcipse 2015 CI 6 has been rebuilt to solve this problem.